# I would like when the bot is online to send me an embed in a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wrote this but it's not right:

```
client.on("ready", (c) => {
  client.channels.cache.get('ID').send({ 
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("Comandi Principali:")
      .setColor("Random")
  })
```

I would like it to send an embed as soon as the bot goes live.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('your-channel-id');
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Comandi Principali:")
        .setColor("#0099ff");
    channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
});
```

Comment: Assuming you required discord.js

Comment: It doesn't work... something else

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: From a Discord API error

Comment: Post the error please

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).